# print random unicode card in console

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm trying to make a method that returns a random card pic in console:

```
def random_card
  x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'].shuffle.join[0]
  y = %w[A B C D].shuffle.join[0]
  card = '\u{1F0' + y.to_s + x.to_s + '}'
  puts card.to_s
end
```

executing this prints

```
\u{1F0BF}
```

but i need same behavior as:

```
puts "\u{1F0BF}"
```

output

Comment: Don't forget [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sample).

Comment: `puts %w(             ).sample`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first answer was wrong I have overseen something but:

How about this (tested):

```
        ... 
        hexnum="1F0#{y}#{x}"
        card=''
        card  << hexnum.to_i(16)
        ...
```

you make the "hex" dynamically, convert it into an integer and push this as first char into string
stolen here https://gist.github.com/O-I/6758583

Comment: @SimpleLime, yes - sure, I have overseen this aspect, working on it

Comment: @SimpleLime: this one I tested, a new answer